# Counting lines of code per author in a git repository

Tags: git, git-branch, author, lines-of-code, cloc

So I'm in a team with a few other programmers and need to get a lines-of-code count per author in our git repository. That doesn't just mean lines modified by author, because that would include blank and comment lines. Ideally, I would be able to make a new branch containing only the commits of a specific author (`--author="BtheDestroyer"` for myself) and then use `cloc` to get the comment line count and code line counts separately. I've tried using

```
git log --author="BtheDestroyer" --format=%H > mycommits
git checkout --orphan mycommits
tac mycommits| while read sha; do git cherry-pick --no-commit ${sha}; done
```

during the last line, however, I get a ton of the following errors:

```
filepath: unmerged (commit-id-1)
filepath: unmerged (commit-id-2)
error: your index file is unmerged.
fatal: cherry-pick failed
```

I'm also not sure if that will end up fastforwarding through other commits in the process. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question:

I ended up using `git blame` and a Bourne shell script to loop through different files in the source folder, convert them back to code using `grep` and `cut`, organize the output into temporary files, and then run `cloc` on that.

Here's my shell script for anyone wanting to do something similar (I have it in `./Blame/` so change `SOURCE` appropriately!):

```
#!/bin/bash
#Name of user to check
#  If you have multiple usernames, separate them with a space
#  The full name is not required, just enough to not be ambiguous
USERS="YOUR USERNAMES HERE"
#Directories
SOURCE=../source

for USER in $USERS
do
    #clear blame files
    echo "" > $USER-Blame.h
    echo "" > $USER-Blame.cpp
    echo "" > $USER-Blame.sh
    echo "Finding blame for $USER..."
    #C++ files
    echo "  Finding blame for C++ files..."
    for f in $SOURCE/*.cpp
    do
        git blame "$f" | grep "$USER" | cut -c 70- >> "$USER-Blame.cpp"
    done
    #Header files
    echo "  Finding blame for Header files..."
    for f in $SOURCE/*.h
    do
        git blame "$f" | grep "$USER" | cut -c 70- >> "$USER-Blame.h"
    done
    #Shell script files
    echo "  Finding blame for shell script files..."
    for f in ./GetUSERBlame.sh
    do
        git blame "$f" | grep "$USER" | cut -c 70- >> "$USER-Blame.sh"
    done
done

for USER in $USERS
do
#cloc
echo "Blame for all users found! Cloc-ing $USER..."
cloc $USER-Blame.* --quiet
#this line is for cleaning up the temporary files
#if you want to save them for future reference, comment this out.
rm $USER-Blame.* -f
done
```

Answer (score 1):

here's my one-liner:

```sh
function gitfilecontributors() { local perfile="false" ; if [[ $1 = "-f" ]]; then perfile="true" ; shift ; fi ; if [[ $# -eq 0 ]]; then echo "no files given!" >&2 ; return 1 ; else local f ; { for f in "$@"; do echo "$f" ; git blame --show-email "$f" | sed -nE 's/^[^ ]* *.<([^>]*)>.*$/: \1/p' | sort | uniq -c | sort -r -nk1 ; done } | if [[ "$perfile" = "true" ]]; then tee /tmp/gitblamestats.txt ; else tee /tmp/gitblamestats.txt >/dev/null ; fi ; echo ; echo "total:" ; awk -v FS=' *: *' '/^ *[0-9]/{sums[$2] += $1} END { for (i in sums) printf("%7s : %s\n", sums[i], i)}' /tmp/gitblamestats.txt | sort -r -nk1 ; fi ; }
```

or with line breaks:

```sh
gitfilecontributors ()
{
    local perfile="false";
    if [[ $1 = "-f" ]]; then
        perfile="true";
        shift;
    fi;
    if [[ $# -eq 0 ]]; then
        echo "no files given!" 1>&2;
        return 1;
    else
        local f;
        {
            for f in "$@";
            do
                echo "$f";
                git blame --show-email "$f" | sed -nE 's/^[^ ]* *.<([^>]*)>.*$/: \1/p' | sort | uniq -c | sort -r -nk1;
            done
        } | if [[ "$perfile" = "true" ]]; then
            tee /tmp/gitblamestats.txt;
        else
            tee /tmp/gitblamestats.txt > /dev/null;
        fi;
        echo;
        echo "total:";
        awk -v FS=' *: *' '/^ *[0-9]/{sums[$2] += $1} END { for (i in sums) printf("%7s : %s\n", sums[i], i)}' /tmp/gitblamestats.txt | sort -r -nk1;
    fi
}
```

usage possible four folder(s) of your choice.

option -f to show per file, otherwise totals only:

```
$ gitfilecontributors    $(fd --type f '.*' source)
```

```
total:
    139 : somebody@somewhere.de
     29 : else.user@somewhere.de
      9 : just.another@somewhere.de
```

```
gitfilecontributors -f $(fd --type f '.*' source)
```

```
source/040_InitialSetup.md
     80 : somebody@somewhere.de
     29 : else.user@somewhere.de
      6 : just.another@somewhere.de
README.md
     59 : somebody@somewhere.de
      5 : whosthat@somewhere.de
      3 : just.another@somewhere.de

total:
    139 : somebody@somewhere.de
     29 : else.user@somewhere.de
      9 : just.another@somewhere.de
      5 : whosthat@somewhere.de
```